# Configure Boost Log V2 Text IPC message queue backend via ini file

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

from the recent documentation, it seems, that Boost Log V2 has been extended with Text IPC message queue backend:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html

but I haven't found any description, how can I configure it via .ini file:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.settings_file

Can anybody help me, where are these settings documented?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in factory for creating text IPC message queue sinks from settings. Mainly because the queue setup protocol, including choosing which process should create the queue, and with what parameters, is the application logic and not a configurable setting.

You can register a custom sink factory as described [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension/settings.html#log.extension.settings.sinks) (you don't need a custom sink as you can use the sink backend provided by Boost.Log). The sink factory should process the settings and create and configure the sink and the associated IPC queue accordingly.